# show dropdown on click for typeahead (runningcoder)

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I am using the typeahead [from runningcoder](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/).

Currently, I am forced to type a search filter in the search field in order to trigger the dropdown portion.

I want to display the dropdown list of available options when I click on the search field, (or focus on it).

```
$('#city_list').typeahead({
    order: "desc",
    highlight: false,
    cache:true,     
    source: {
        data: allCities
    },
     callback: {
            onClick: function (node, a, obj, e) {
                $('#city_list').select();
                loadCityDetails();
            }
        },
    });
```

As you can see, the onClick refers to the click of the item in the dropdown list, not the search field itself.

A click handler on the search field yields no results

```
$('body').on('click', '#city_list', function(event) {
    alert('hellooo');
})
```

How can I force the list of available options to show when I click the search field?

JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/57pL6gdd/

**UPDATE:**
This feature has now been added to version 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Try using focus as opposed to click:

```
$('#city_list').focus().typeahead({
order: "desc",
highlight: false,
cache:true,     
source: {
    data: allCities
},
 callback: {
        onClick: function (node, a, obj, e) {
            $('#city_list').select();
            loadCityDetails();
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that usage does not work. Still no dropdown,

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and we can see it in action

Comment: Great suggestion. Added jsfiddle to main post. Looks a bit wonky, but the code is there.

Comment: This plugin has an example of the effect I require. Click on the empty search to see the item dropdown being displayed.

Comment: have a look at this :  http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/ This has the effect I require. When I click in the empty search field, it shows the dropdown of all options. Your jsfiddle does not (in Firefox 31.0.1).

Comment: Ah ok, I see - you'd have to look at the typeahead source code for that, it would need some changes

Comment: Logged issue : https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/issues/29#issuecomment-78381514 so the feature is not currently supported.

Comment: This feature has now been added as per the logged issue to version 2 of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are attaching the click handler to the search field and not the list?

Judging by the second code snippet the selector you are using is #city_list, which according to the first code snippet is the list of available options after something has been typed in.

```
$('body').on('click', '#search_field', function(event) {
    alert('hellooo');
})
```

Change the above '#search_field' selector to the one you are using for your search field.

Comment: #city_list is the search field, and is used in the markup for the typeahead. I updated my post.